# How to get data from Json with Python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to fetch data from an api with this code, and get "NomParc" for example. I have tried the following code... any help?
Sorry as I know it is a very newbie question... I am trying.

---

```
import json
import urllib2


url="https://www.apiurl"

json_obj= urllib2.urlopen(url)

data=json.load(json_obj)

collect=data['results']

for item in data:
    for data2 in data['results']:
        for data3 in data2['collection1']:
            print data3
```

---

here is my json structure than I get from url variable.

```
{
  "name": "Page Park wiki",
  "count": 480,
  "frequency": "Manual Crawl",
  "version": 3,
  "newdata": true,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "thisversionrun": "Sat Oct 17 2015 13:05:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "NomParc": "1er arrondissement de Paris",
        "Lat": {
          "href": "http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?language=fr&pagename=1er_arrondissement_de_Paris&params=48.859947_N_2.342059_E_type:city_region:fr",
          "text": "48° 51′ 36″ N"
        },
        "Long": {
          "href": "http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?language=fr&pagename=1er_arrondissement_de_Paris&params=48.859947_N_2.342059_E_type:city_region:fr",
          "text": "2° 20′ 31″ E"
        },....
```

Comment: Is this the output of json_obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to do json.loads(), not json.load()

After json.loads(), data is just like any other dictionary which you can access.

So `data['results']['collection1'][0]['NomPrac']` will give you the output.

Here is the code:

```
for item in collect:
  for i in collect[item]:
    print i['NomPrac']
```

Comment: Great! Would appreciate if you accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi, I got an other issue, that the output is not a string that I can use but a unicode...

Comment: You can convert it using str() function. In this case: str(i['NomPrac']) or if it contains extra characters like $, you could using encoding. i['NomPrac'].encode('utf-8')

Comment: I used another module "unidecode", because i needed no ^éè ...etc. Thanks for your help.